# Work with many-to many relationships C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Good evening!
I use Asp.net MVC with EF.
I have 2 models

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Category> categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> products { get; set; }
    }
```

many-to many add normaly work, if I add new product, but if i try update product entity,new relationship doesnt add.
I add new products like this

```
Product product= new Product{...};
product.categories.Add(db.Categories.First())//example
```

How I can add/delete relationships in product entity update?

Comment: Basically the same way. But instead of `new Product` you get the existing from the database - something like `db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == productId)`

Answer (score 0):

First, your `ICollection<T>` should be a virtual property:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Next, create an association table between the two:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your dbContext, add the relationships:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>()
       .HasKey(c => new { c.CategoryId, c.ProductId });

   modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
       .HasMany(c => c.ProductCategories)
       .WithRequired()
       .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductId);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
       .HasMany(c => c.ProductCategories)
       .WithRequired()
       .HasForeignKey(c => c.CategoryId);  
}
```

Comment: But Entity framework automatic create association table

Comment: And `virtual` is not required.

Comment: Are you using Fluent API? If so, you can check here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Yes, in new product add, many-to many inserts work fine, but if itry update product, new relationships dont added

Comment: Did you try this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417849/unable-to-update-foreign-key-in-entity-framework-6