# How to Detect Change on 1-N

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Simple question. I didn't have this problem using NHibernate, but now I have it with EntityFramework:

Imagine that I have a Car, with a list of Tires.

I want to remove 1 tire of a car, so I want to update it.
Something like:

```
Car.Tires.Remove(tire);
```

And then I update the car object with this update method:

```
public virtual void Update(T obj)
{
     TryAttach(obj);
     SetAllModified(obj);
     SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is that after the update, the car still have the same amount of tires.

How can I update the list of Tires when I call the update method?

Comment: Is Car the name of your context object, or is it just one of your models?

Comment: Car is the entity (model).

Comment: Where does the tire object come from? If you got it from the database it should work.

Comment: What is the Car object? Is it your DbContext? If your Car is an Entity then SaveChanges should really live on the context.

Comment: Car is my entity. That seems wierd then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the tire in the database and then remove it:

```
var tire=context.Tires.Where(t=>t.Name==tireName).Single();
Car.Tires.Remove(tire);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: what the hell. On Nhibernate I simple call Car.SaveOrUpdate() and then the list of tires get updated without needing to calculate what tire was removed.

Comment: Do not use .First() when you mean .Single()

Comment: In entityframework it is not working like that look at this maybe it will give you direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606866/cannot-get-relationship-to-update-for-navigation-properties-in-entity-framework

Comment: look at BenjaminPaul answer this is what I meant, it is more detailed!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is something a little strange about the way you have things setup... without a little more code it's hard to work out what you are doing but here is what I would expect if I was to do this myself with Entity Framework.

Firstly... you need a DbContext, your context would look something like this...

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tyre> Tires { get; set; }
}
```

Then some pocos...

```
public class Car {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tyre> Tires { get; set; }
}

public class Tyre {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    // More properties...

    [ForeignKey("CarId")]
    public virtual int CarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

Then I would expect you to do something like this.... my brain is not working quite the same after a long day but essentially.. remove the tire you no longer need from the Car object you loaded from the database then save your changes.

```
using (var context = new SomeContext())
{
    var car = context.Cars.Find(carId);
    var tyre = car.Tires.Single(t => t.Id == tireId);
    car.Tires.Remove(tyre);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's what I am already doing, but I'm not using code-first. It still not working =/